# Xml Deserialize with Native AOT

Tags: c#, xml, native, xml-deserialization, aot

I want to deserialize xml document to c# object.

Xml document example

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="LayoutControl">
  <property name="#LayoutVersion" />
  <property name="OptionsFocus" isnull="true" iskey="true">
    <property name="ActivateSelectedControlOnGotFocus">true</property>
    <property name="AllowFocusControlOnLabelClick">false</property>
    <property name="EnableAutoTabOrder">true</property>
    <property name="AllowFocusControlOnActivatedTabPage">false</property>
    <property name="AllowFocusGroups">true</property>
    <property name="AllowFocusTabbedGroups">true</property>
    <property name="AllowFocusReadonlyEditors">true</property>
    <property name="MoveFocusRightToLeft">false</property>
    <property name="MoveFocusDirection">AcrossThenDown</property>
  </property>
  <property name="Items" iskey="true" value="2">
    <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="TypeName">LayoutGroup</property>
      <property name="TabbedGroupParentName" />
      <property name="GroupBordersVisible">false</property>
      <property name="AllowDrawBackground">true</property>
      <property name="EnableIndentsWithoutBorders">True</property>
      <property name="OptionsItemText" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="TextToControlDistance">4</property>
        <property name="TextAlignMode">UseParentOptions</property>
      </property>
      <property name="CaptionImageVisible">true</property>
      <property name="FlowDirection">LeftToRight</property>
      <property name="LayoutMode">Regular</property>
      <property name="CaptionImageLocation">Default</property>
      <property name="CaptionImageIndex">-1</property>
      <property name="AllowBorderColorBlending">false</property>
      <property name="ExpandOnDoubleClick">false</property>
      <property name="Expanded">true</property>
      <property name="DefaultLayoutType">Vertical</property>
      <property name="ShowTabPageCloseButton">false</property>
      <property name="AllowHtmlStringInCaption">false</property>
      <property name="AllowGlyphSkinning">Default</property>
      <property name="OptionsTableLayoutGroup" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="RowDefinitions" iskey="true" value="0" />
        <property name="ColumnDefinitions" iskey="true" value="0" />
      </property>
      <property name="Size">@4,Width=1318@3,Height=554</property>
      <property name="ExpandButtonVisible">false</property>
      <property name="ExpandButtonMode">Normal</property>
      <property name="HeaderButtonsLocation">Default</property>
      <property name="GroupStyle">Inherited</property>
      <property name="TextLocation">Top</property>
      <property name="TabPageWidth">0</property>
      <property name="OptionsCustomization" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="AllowDrag">Default</property>
        <property name="AllowDrop">Default</property>
      </property>
      <property name="OptionsTableLayoutItem" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="RowIndex">0</property>
        <property name="RowSpan">1</property>
        <property name="ColumnIndex">0</property>
        <property name="ColumnSpan">1</property>
      </property>
      <property name="OptionsToolTip" isnull="true" iskey="true">
        <property name="ToolTip" />
        <property name="ToolTipTitle" />
        <property name="ToolTipIconType">None</property>
        <property name="ImmediateToolTip">false</property>
        <property name="AllowHtmlString">Default</property>
        <property name="IconToolTip" />
        <property name="IconToolTipTitle" />
        <property name="IconToolTipIconType">None</property>
        <property name="EnableIconToolTip">true</property>
        <property name="IconImmediateToolTip">false</property>
        <property name="IconAllowHtmlString">Default</property>
      </property>
      <property name="Name">Root</property>
      <property name="ParentName" />
      <property name="TextVisible">false</property>
      <property name="Location">@1,X=0@1,Y=0</property>
      <property name="ShowInCustomizationForm">true</property>
      <property name="Text">Root</property>
      <property name="CustomizationFormText">Root</property>
      <property name="StartNewLine">false</property>
      <property name="Visibility">Always</property>
    </property>
  </property>
</XtraSerializer>
```

Now I want to deserialize from xml string to c# object.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "property")]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
    public List<Property> property { get; set; }    
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XtraSerializer")]
public class XtraSerializer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
    public List<Property> Property { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

XtraSerializer GetXtraSerializer(string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XtraSerializer));
            using StringReader reader = new (xml);
            return (XtraSerializer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

It works normally before publish. After publish with Native AOT exception occurs.
There is an error in XML document (0, 0).

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)

Comment: Xml deserialization uses reflection under hood. AOT is not friendly with reflection.

Comment: Look at [Using Microsoft XML Serializer Generator on .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator). Maybe it help.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works.  All I did was change the StringReader :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XtraSerializer xtra = GetXtraSerializer(xml);
        }
        static XtraSerializer GetXtraSerializer(string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XtraSerializer));
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            return (XtraSerializer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "property")]
    public class Property
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
        public List<Property> property { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "XtraSerializer")]
    public class XtraSerializer
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "property")]
        public List<Property> Property { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried AOT?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov : why use a third party app when you can do same with standard libraries?

Comment: @jdweng - AOT isn't a third party library, it's a way of building and publishing, and stands for "Ahead Of Time".  From [Native AOT deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/): *Publishing your app as Native AOT produces an app that's self-contained and that has been ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled to native code.*

Comment: @mvermef: What link?

Answer (score 0):

I used [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm) for this. First I converted to json and then to c# object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).